# How to do make this regular expression work? (Consecutive delimiter)

Tags: java, regex, split

I am using the following code:

```
String array[] = "aba;b12".split("[4\\,;\\Qab\\E]+");
for(String test : array)
    System.out.println(test);
```

I expect:

```
a
b12
```

However I get:

```
<blank line>
12
```

Edit:  I cleaned up the code, sorry.

The whole Idea is to splt the code by 4, semicolon, ab, comma, and treat consecutive delimiter as one.

Edit: Sorry about all the confusion, I know the question was not as clear as it could have been.

Thanks

Comment: What is the contents of `temp`?

Comment: Why do you expect that? Your splitting RE matches strings of characters that include `a` and `b`; why would you expect to find those in the split-off substrings?

Comment: (I'm assuming that `temp` contains the same thing you've passed to `split` in the line above. Is that right?)

Comment: this code is not understandable... also, what regex would you need to get "a", "b" and "12" from "aba;b12"!?

Comment: @jmp temp was just a code and paste error, basically.  see the updated code

Comment: @f1sh Basically, I want to split it by ab.

Comment: @Grae: Please give us a well thought-out description of the list of things you think should act as a delimiter.  It is completely unclear which things you think should be delimiters here and which shouldn't.

Comment: @Mark Peter I just need a string delimiter and more than one char delimiter

Comment: @Mark 4, comma, semicolon, and ab were the delimiters I was trying to get.

Comment: @Grae: But where's the delimiter between "b" and "12"?  You're for some reason expecting those to be split but I see no reason for them to be.

Comment: You right it should a the b12 on the next line. I am just confused that the a and the b disappear.

Comment: @Grae if you want to split by ``ab``, then don't place those in a character class. Use ``split("([4\,;]||ab)+")`` instead. the \Q and \E does not 'glue' them together!

Comment: @fish I did not realize about them getting split apart.  That was the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've finally worked out what you think `\Q...\E` is doing. What I think you want is `([4\,;]|ab)+` (plus any necessary escaping if you're writing it as a string literal). Er, except that I don't understand why you've bothered escaping the comma.

Comment: I tought , have to be escaped.  It thought it have some special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think \Qab\E isn't doing what you think it is, the regex will split by any character inside the square brackets so will split at a and b, try this instead:

Edit:

```
([4\,;]+)
```

I didn't quite read that correctly, that will give you

```
ab
b12
```

But the first part stands.

Comment: How do I get "ab" rather than a and b?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is a little outside the scope of what a regular expression is intended for. Perhaps you should rephrase your question to include what you are trying to achieve and people could give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
String array[] = "aba;b12".split("ab|,|;|4");
for(String test : array)
    System.out.println(test);
```

outputs

```
<blank line>
a
b12
```

Comment: The <blank line> comes from the "null" char before the first 'ab' delimiter.

Comment: That does not work for aba;;b12

Answer (score 0):

IYou can not split `"aba;b12"` to get

```
a
b
12
```

You have to define what you wish to do and define the rule for it if you wish to use Regex. If its about parsing each letter alone and the numbers together you will have  to do that manually or modify the original string so you can split it usign regex.
If you give some background information on what you wish to achieve maby you will get some new Ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String array[] = "aba;;b12".split("(\\Qab\\E+|[4;]+)+");
    for(String test : array)
        System.out.println(test);
```